# IAM condition expression to allow named file upload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I have a bucket named `bucket-hr-data`. There is one folder in it named `payroll`.

I am trying to create a service account `sa-payroll` that can manage files/folders under that folder only.

This is how my IAM condition looks like for the service account.

```
resource.name.extract("projects/_/buckets/bucket-hr-data/objects/{name}/")=='payroll'
```

This works for the most part except that when I try to upload a file with a name.

> gsutil cp ./somefile.txt gs://bucket-hr-data/payroll/payroll/ - works
> as expected
>
> gsutil cp ./somefile.txt
> gs://bucket-hr-data/payroll/payroll/data1/ - works as expected
>
> gsutil cp ./somefile.txt gs://bucket-hr-data/payroll/payroll/somefile.txt - unexpectedly fails with 403

How do I change the IAM condition expression so that all 3 commands work?

Comment: You have a terminating (`/`) in your `extract` value (`extract("project ... /")`). This is looking for names that end in a slash and `somefile.txt` does not.

Comment: without terminating `/`, the behavior is very unexpected. None of the commands work.

Comment: I would use `resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/bucket-hr-data/objects/payroll/payroll/")`

Comment: @JohnHanley: It is technically the same thing. `payroll/` or `payroll/payroll/`. Same behavior. Cannot upload file using `gsutil cp ./newfile.txt gs://bucket-hr-data/payroll/payroll/somefile.txt`

Comment: Show your entire condition. Commands 1 and 3 should result in the same object name and result in the same condition. A detail is missing.

Comment: there is only one line in the condition editor: `resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/bucket-hr-data/objects/payroll/payroll/")`. command `gsutil cp ./newfile.txt gs://bucket-hr-data/payroll/payroll/sa.txt` fails. command `gsutil cp ./newfile.txt gs://bucket-hr-data/payroll/payroll/` works. I need both of them to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your bucket's access control could be fine-grained. Conditions to IAM policies for Cloud Storage is [only available](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#attributes) for buckets that use uniform bucket-level access.

The solution if you want to configure access on your buckets using IAM conditions is to [enable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-uniform-bucket-level-access#enable) uniform bucket-level access.

My test bucket has uniform level access and this IAM condition works fine. Change your IAM condition to:

```
resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/BUCKET_NAME/objects/payroll/payroll/")
```

---

**UPDATE:** Check your IAM role. If your service account only has `Storage Object Creator` and
`Storage Object Viewer` role, then trying to upload an object that already exists in the bucket object will return a 403 as the object creator role don't have permission to **delete** an object.

Comment: No. Bucket access control is Uniform.

Comment: @Asdfg There must be something we're missing and I think it has to do with your IAM, where the service account only has permission to upload an object, but not *replace* it. I updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Service account has Object Storage Admin role.

Comment: @Asdfg it may seem redundant, but please try adding `Storage Object Viewer` role on your service account. Wait for a few minutes, then let me know if it works or not. Overall, the roles should be `Storage Object Admin` (condition is applied here) and `Storage Object Viewer`

Comment: It works as expected only if I give `Storage Object Viewer` permissions at the bucket level. I guess that is because `cp` has to list the content of the bucket to figure out if the prefix `payroll` needs to be created or not.